# Getting wrong output when try to run SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying below query but not getting proper output. It will return me garbage value.

I have try this query :

```
select convert(nvarchar(max), '.4ah開発進捗状況（週報）')
```

Output of my query :

```
.4ah??????(??)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding 'N' before your chinese string, it simply converts your string to unicode. Just check this:

```
select convert(nvarchar(max), N'.4ah開発進捗状況（週報）')
```

Using 'N' prefix means declaring the string as nvarchar data type, rather than varchar.